# tail -f a file for 10 minutes / until N matching lines?

Tags: tail

I've got a log file that I process as follows:

```
grep pattern /var/log/whatever.log | \
    cut ... | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | \
    etc....
```

However, the log file is quite big, and records events from the beginning of the day. It's also appended to constantly. I'd like to only process the <del>last</del> next 10 minutes of the file.

So I'm looking for something like the following:

```
killafter 600 tail -f /var/log/whatever.log | stuff
```

Or, better yet (wait however long it takes to capture 1000 matching lines):

```
tail -f /var/log/whatever.log | grep pattern | stopafter -lines 1000 | stuff
```

Are there any tools that'll let me do this?

Comment: Look for the `timeout` command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

roaima rightly points you at the `timeout` command, and `head` actually terminates after it has read the desired number of lines, so I would hope that with

```
timeout 600s tail -f ‹logfile› | ‹filter› | head -n 1000
```

you'd get there.

Comment: That is a good answer I had difficulty with `head` never seems to take `stdin` properly. Try `timeout 600s tail -f /var/log/whatever.log | grep -m 1000 pattern`

Answer (score 1):

By default, timeout kills the process and the pipe gets killed.

```
timeout --foreground 600s tail -n 0 -f logfile | ...filter | head -n 1000| ...
```

- `timeout --foreground` otherwise we would see just "Terminated"
- `tail -n 0 -f` to show only the new loglines
- `head -n 1000` to "stop after 1000 lines"

\thanks{roaima and Ulrich Schwarz}

Comment: How is this different to Ulrich Schwarz's answer?

Comment: @roaima, Ulrich Schwartz's answer, gets "terminated" and prints no output in case of timeout.

Comment: @roaima  and Ulrich, unfortunately my answer is not working properly too: in case of obtaining "1000 lines", it prints the answer but the "timout"  process continues :(

Answer (score 0):

This `perl` code will give you a *counted `tail`*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# Usage tailmax.pl <filename> [<num_lines>]
#
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Tail;

my $logfile = shift @ARGV;
my $pattern = shift @ARGV || '';
my $count = shift @ARGV || -1;

my $fh = File::Tail->new(name => $logfile, tail => 0, interval => 0, maxinterval => 2) or
    die "Cannot open $logfile: $!\n";

while ($count != 0 and defined (my $line = $fh->read)) {
    if ($pattern eq '' or $line =~ /$pattern/) {
        print "$line";
        $count-- if $count > 0;
    }
}
```

If you save it to a file such as `/usr/local/bin/tailmax` and make it executable, you can call it like this, which will give you the next 100 messages from the log file `/var/log/messages` that contain the RE `somepattern`. (You may need to be `root` to read this file.)

```
tailmax /var/log/messages 'somepattern' 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below command and it worked fine

```
tail -f /var/log/file.log & read -t 600; kill $!
```

This would run `tail -f` on the file in the background, and then use `read` with a timeout set to 10 minutes.  When the `read` returns, either because the user pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or because of timing out, the background `tail -f` job is killed.

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulty with the answer from [Ulrich Schwarz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308835/280026) because `head` never seems to look at `stdin` so try the following if it may be of assistance.

`timeout 600s tail -f {logfile} | grep -m 1000 {pattern}`

Good Luck!